# Division with remainder in $\mathbb R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, divisibility

If $a,b\in\mathbb R$ with $b\ne0$, how precisely is division with remainder of $a$ by $b$ defined?

It should be something like $a=bc+r$ for some $c\in\mathbb Z$ and $r\in[0,|b|)$.

However, I'm interested in the case $b=1$. If, for example, $a=-0.1$, I would expect that $a\operatorname{mod}1=0.9$. So, $c=-1$ and $r=0.9$. However, $c=0$ and $r=-0.1$ would also been possible if we would allow $r$ to be negative. Does it matter? And is $c$ unique?

**EDIT**: I guess we need to choose $c=\lfloor\frac ab\rfloor$.

Comment: Well, dividing $a$ by $b$ gives $\frac ab\in\Bbb R$, so... Are you sure that you want to work in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: In more algebraic terms, what you are looking for is the unique representative $c$ for the coset $a + b\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with $c\in [0,|b|)$.

Comment: @mrtaurho Where do you see the problem? We could choose $c=\lfloor\frac ab\rfloor$. This would yield my desired result in the example with $b=1$ and $a=-0.1$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I suppose I missed your point. I did not see why it should be sensible to define division with remainder in a *field*, where you can invert anything per se, i.e. $\frac ab$ is always already defined.

Comment: @mrtaurho As I wrote before, I'm mainly interested in $b=1$. And the sense of defining $\iota(a):=a\operatorname{mod}1$ is that it yields the fractional part of $a$ (where negative values are wrapped around). For me it gives a way to define $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ to be $\mathbb R/\ker\iota$.